# NSLocalizedString in iWatch

Tags: swift, xcode8, watchos-2

I make my app localized for two language in the iWatch. Most of the text get localized except in the Complication and the Alert dialog.

Could anyone help me?

Code for Alert

```
    let restartAction = WKAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: ""), style: .destructive, handler: {
        //some code here
    })

    let cancelAction = WKAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), style: .cancel, handler: {})

    presentAlert(withTitle: NSLocalizedString("Restart the page?", comment: ""), message: "", preferredStyle: .alert, actions: [restartAction, cancelAction])
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Which apple localisation documentation have you looked at?

Comment: I use this function to make localization: NSLocalizedString("Page", comment: "")

Comment: Did you add the texts to your `Localizable.strings` file?

Comment: Yes, I did. I used the same text in the WKInterfaceButton and Alert, in the WKInterfaceButton get localized, but in the Alert doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem:

select the localizable.string file and in the file inspector>Target Membership put check mark on Watch Extension.